# curl: (52) Empty reply from server in case of huge file

Tags: curl

When i am using curl & if file is in big size like 500MB+ in such case i am getting curl: (52) Empty reply from server error.
If pulling file is small then it works fine.
But in case of big file only it give this error.
I dont know exact big size for which it gives error but yes one file getting generated on server side which is 615MB & for that it is giving that error.
Is there any size or time out setting I need to do on server/Client side?
Please help. I dont know much about curl.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with a curl request I made to a node.js http server. The problem is not curl but the http server. Node's http server has a default timeout of 2 minutes as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) which describes how to set it yourself.

I know it's a bit late, but next time try to notice if the curl request constantly times out at the same time e.g. was always 2 minutes in my case. This hinted me to check the server side.